# Is it possible to create a table structure to an existing data in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, format

I have some data that is organized properly in MS word 2007. Now I need to put this data into a table structure. Since there is so much of such data I just cant manually arrange them. Is there a way to do it in Word?

**This is how my data is-**
[image]

**And this is how I want-**
[image]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Have you tried the `text to table` conversion?

Comment: yes I tried text to table conversion. But that seems to work on plain text only. In the format that I have my text, though I give commas, text to convert option is still disabled.